# Gnome, Win/Alt+Tab, show thumbnail instead of app icon?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Both Alt+Tab/Win+Tab shows a switcher pop-up like below. Can I make actual window thumbnail show instead of the icon?

Gnome 41.3, Manjaro, Wayland.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/968/alternatetababove/), if you have theability to.

Comment: This seems like a weird problem of Manjaro (or the version of Gnome that Manjaro uses, 41.5). I have tested it on Ubuntu 21.10, and on it, Alt+Tab shows window thumbnails by default. Win+Tab was the same as the Manjaro screen above.